# ¿Cómo animar proceso según el valor recibido de PHP a jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, css3

Mediante `PHP` se van contabilizando los pasos y añadiendoles en una sesión para evitar regresar al principio en caso de actualizar o refrescar la página, el valor es obtenido por medio de la siguiente variable `$step`

```
<?php
  session_start();

  if ( !empty($_SESSION['datos_form']['__step__'])) {
    $step = $_SESSION['datos_form']['__step__'];
  } else {
    $step = '1';
  }

?>
```

El valor de la variable la recibimos en el código `javascript` de **jQuery**.

```
show_step(<?= $step; ?>);
```

Que sería igual a: *(por el valor default recibido)*

```
show_step(1);
```

Cada paso del proceso se va mostrando según el valor recibido de `PHP` al código `Javascript` como ya lo venía mencionando.

Sin la necesidad de tener que añadir controles adicionales como lo siguiente:

```
current = $(this).parent();
next = $(this).parent().next();
```

> Para luego así saber mediante la animación en que paso del proceso se encuentra el formulario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

El problema se encuentra en la siguiente `function`

```
function animacion(caso){
  $( ".cartanime" ).animate({ "left": "+=250px" }, "slow" ,function(){
    $(".progressbar li").addClass("active");  
  });
};
```

Activa todos los `li` con la clase `actve` al continuar con los pasos del **wizard** y al seguir con el restos de pasos, o al retroceder para atrás los `active` quedan activados.

Y el `icono` del carrito que se va deslizando en la barra de progreso, va aumentando el `left` al continuar de la misma manera y al retroceder para atrás también va aumentando todo sin control.

**Mi código:**

```js
$(function() {
    show_step(<?= $step; ?>);        
});

// funcion animar proceso
function animacion(caso){
  $( ".cartanime" ).animate({ "left": "+=250px" }, "slow" ,function(){
    $(".progressbar li").addClass("active");  
  });
};

// funcion para guardar los datos del form y cambiar el paso
function show_step(step){
    var data = $( "#form" ).serialize();
    var url = 'saveTemp.php?step=' + step;
    
    // realizamos la peticion ajax
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: data
    })
    .done(function( resp ) {
        // si todo va bien
        // ocultamos los pasos
        $('.step').css( "display", "none" );
        // mostramos el paso correspondiente
        $('#step'+step).fadeIn("slow");
        //movemos la animación al paso correspondiente
        animacion(step);
    });
};
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 73px;
}

.progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.progressbar li > * {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  color: #2c3f4c;
  top: -45px;
}

.progressbar li:before {
  content: '';
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  display: block;
  text-align:  center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #edeff0;
}
  
.progressbar li:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #edeff0;
  top: 4px;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: -1;
}
  
.progressbar li:first-child:after {
  content: none;
}
  
.progressbar li.active {
  color: green;
}
  
.progressbar li.active:before {
  background-color: green;
}
  
.progressbar li.active + li:after {
  background-color: green;
}

.cartanime {
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  background: url(https://media.dermstore.com/images/style/bootstrap3/img/cart-icon.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 30px;
  top: 73px;
  left: 450px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="progressbar">
    <li class="active"><span>Step 1</span></li>
    <li><span>Step 2</span></li>
    <li><span>Step 3</span></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="cartanime"></div>
</div>

<form id="form" action="procesar.php">
  <div id="step1" class="step">
   <h1>Paso 1</h1>
   <a data-ref="#" onclick="show_step(2)">continuar</a>
  </div>
  <div id="step2" class="step">
   <h1>Paso 2</h1>
   <a data-ref="#" onclick="show_step(1)">Atras</a>
    <a data-ref="#" onclick="show_step(3)">continuar</a>
  </div>
  <div id="step3" class="step">
   <h1>Paso 3</h1>
   <a data-ref="#" onclick="show_step(2)">Atras</a>
    <button>Enviar</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Disculpa, no acabo de entender bien. ¿Cual es el uso de la función `animación` y por qué no hace uso de su parámetro `caso`?

Comment: @delCano Realmente quería ver si existía otra forma que no sea utilizar un `switch` dentro de la  función `function animacion(caso)` por eso no estaba dando su uso...

Comment: ¿Un `switch`? ¿Por qué no `...animate({ "left": caso*250+"px" }...` y `$(".progressbar li:nth-child("+caso+")")...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voy a formular mis comentarios en una respuesta que creo será más cómoda de ver.

El problema está únicamente en la función animación, que debe llevar al paso correcto y actualmente activa todos de golpe. Yo la cambiaría a:

```js
function animacion(caso){
  var pixels = (caso * 250) + "px";

  $(".progressbar li.active").removeClass("active");
  
  $( ".cartanime" ).animate({ "left": pixels }, "slow" ,function(){
    for(var i = 1; i <= caso; i++) {
       $(`.progressbar li:nth-child(${i})`).addClass("active");  
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: El ejemplo que has dado funciona, pero solo va activando el paso que está, si ya estoy en el paso 3, solo se activa el tercer `li`  y los otros no...

Comment: Oh, había entendido mal. El cambio que acabo de realizar (el añadido del bucle `for`) debería solucionarlo.

Comment: funciona perfecto, solo que no se porque hace un tipo de traba en añadir la clase `active` al continuar los pasos hace un apagado de unos 4 segundos y aparece la clase activada de la barra... ***Esto se puede solucionar con los estilos css, o es el código de su respuesta que causa este efecto???***

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con un "apagado de unos 4 segundos"?

Comment: Es como si demorara en añadir la clase `active` es decir demora unos 4 segundos en que añada la barra verde en el paso que se encuentra a eso me refiero...

Comment: pero me imagino que esto se puede solucionar con los estilos CSS, porque el código que has dado funciona a lo esperado...

Comment: ¿Tienes un enlace a dónde estás probando el código? No debería demorarse.

Comment: No, he dicho una tontería. La función que da las clases "active" se ejecuta al terminar la animación, tal y como la escribiste. Si te refieres a ese tiempo, entonces es normal. También es fácil de cambiar si lo prefieres.

Comment: no, no lo tengo lo estoy haciendo desde localhost, voy hacer unos cambios en el código CSS y te comento si existe una solución ahí...

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70331/discussion-between-j-doe-and-delcano).

Answer (score 2):

Creo que realmente va hacer imposible no usar `switch` al menos que se utilice algunos otros parámetros / controles / lógica / operaciones, dentro de la función: `function animacion(caso){}` donde puedas saber cuándo retroceder (atrás) para realizar un `-1` y al continuar realizar un `+1` no creo que se pueda usar algo así:

```
-caso +caso
```

> Pero planteó la duda a discusión...

Se debe tomar en cuenta el parámetro `(caso)` de la misma forma de su anterior animación *[(historial de edición)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/123605/revisions)* **sprite**  usando `switch`

**Ejemplo:**

```
function animacion(caso){
    switch(caso) {
        case 1:
          $( ".cartanime" ).animate({ "left": "450px" }, "slow" ,function(){
            $(".progressbar li:nth-child(1)").addClass("active");
          });
          break;
        case 2:
          $( ".cartanime" ).animate({ "left": "900px" }, "slow" ,function(){
            $(".progressbar li:nth-child(2)").addClass("active");
          });
          break;
        case 3:
          //
          break;
        // -> # code...
    };
};
```

Ahora solo debe ir cambiando los valores del `cartanime` en donde desea mostrarlo en cada paso respectivo.

Y si va añadir más pasos, ir cambiando el valor numérico `(2)` de la siguiente condición CSS `li:nth-child(2)` ejemplo en el tercer `li` que tiene en su **wizard** añadir de la siguiente manera: `li:nth-child(3)` y así sucesivamente entre más pasos, sí se añaden más en el **wizard**.

Comment: ¿Por qué un Switch para calcular lo que fundamentalmente son valores "caso" y "caso*450"? ¿No es más fácil insertar los resultados de los cálculos en la cadena y no hacer un switch?

Comment: @delCano Es lo que más mejor me ha parecido.... Ahora Usted aún puede dar una respuesta, la pregunta aún está activa la recompensa de la pregunta aún se encuentra visible... Ahora Ud puede aportará con una respuesta explicando lo que menciona... Saludos!