# Tratamiento de URL para evitar errores

Tags: php, url

Quisiera saber si existe alguna función o método **para evaluar cuando el usuario ingrese en la URL texto no deseado o datos erróneos que puedan "hacer mal funcionamiento" de la web.** Es decir: si borra alguna extensión de la URL o inserta caracteres no deseados, que en vez de devolver un error como:

```
Notice: Undefined index: idcabana in C:\xampp\htdocs\daw\modificar.php on line 57
No existe el ID
```

Podamos tener la opción de mostrar una pantalla personalizada para dicho error para que sea más visible y usable (usando W3C o HTML5 o CSS), a modo prueba, con poner un mensaje en forma de echo "" sería suficiente.

**Ejemplo:** si borramos de `http://localhost/daw/modificar.php?idcabana=3`, los últimos 4-5 caracteres, y pulsamos Enter, tenemos la siguiente URL: `http://localhost/daw/modificar.php?idcaba`, lo cual no tiene ningún dato y todos los datos que sean pasados a esta página serán no reconocidos, para evitar problemas, poner un echo....

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso como esperaba un dato "idcabana" y no lo encuentra en la URL, da el error de "Undefined index: idcabana".

**Código HTML/PHP:**

```
<?php
    require_once "Clases/BD.php";
    require_once "Clases/Cabanas.php";
    require_once "Clases/Accesorios.php";
    require_once "conexion.php";
    //Si existe la sesión "administrador"..., la guardamos en una variable.
    if (isset($_SESSION['administrador'])){
        $administrador = $_SESSION['administrador'];
    }

    //Si pulsamos el botón "Modificar"...
    if(isset($_POST["modificar"])){
        $idcabana = $_POST["idcabana"];
        $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
        $capacidad = $_POST["capacidad"];
        $descripcion = $_POST["descripcion"];
        $precio = $_POST["precio"];
        $array_accesorios = $_POST["accesorios"];
        BD::modificarCabana($idcabana, $nombre, $capacidad, $descripcion, $precio);
        BD::modificarAccesoriosPorCabana($idcabana, $array_accesorios);
        header("Refresh:0; url=panel_administrador.php");
    }

    //Si pulsamos el botón "Atras"...
    if(isset($_POST["atras"])){
        header("Refresh:0; url=panel_administrador.php");
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">    
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Modificar cabaña</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos_modificar.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        function in_multiarray($elemento, $array, $campo){
            $top = sizeof($array) - 1;
            $bottom = 0;
            while($bottom <= $top){
                if($array[$bottom][$campo] == $elemento)
                    return true;
                else 
                    if(is_array($array[$bottom][$campo]))
                        if(in_multiarray($elemento, ($array[$bottom][$campo])))
                            return true;
                $bottom++;
            }        
            return false;
        }

        //Guardamos en una variable los ids de las cabañas.
        $ids = BD::obtenerIDsCabanas();
        //Si ese id no está en la tabla cabanas, mostramos un error.
        if(!in_multiarray($_REQUEST["idcabana"], $ids, "idcabana")){
            echo "No existe el ID";
        }else{
        ?>
        <div id="sesion_administrador">
            <?php 
            if(isset($_SESSION['administrador'])){
                echo "Bienvenido ".$administrador."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                echo "<a href='salir_administrador.php?salir=1'>Salir</a>"; //GET
                //_REQUEST = $_POST o $_GET
                if(isset($_REQUEST["salir"])){
                    unset($_SESSION["administrador"]);
                    header("Refresh:0; url=iniciar_sesion_administrador.php");
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>
        <br/><br/><br/>
        <div id="mostrar_datos">
            <!-- Modificar cabaña -->
            <form action="modificar.php" name="modificar" id="modificar" method="POST">
            <?php $objeto_cabana = BD::datosCabana($_REQUEST["idcabana"]); ?>
                <label for="idcabana">ID: </label>
                    <?php $longitud_idcabana = strlen($objeto_cabana->getIdcabana()); ?>
                    <input type="text" size="<?php echo $longitud_idcabana; ?>" id="idcabana" name="idcabana" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $objeto_cabana->getIdcabana(); ?> "/>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <!-- Aqui va: <br/><br/> -->
                <label for="nombre">Nombre: </label>
                    <?php $longitud_nombre = strlen($objeto_cabana->getNombre()); ?>
                    <input type="text" size="<?php echo $longitud_nombre; ?>" id="nombre" name="nombre" value="<?php echo $objeto_cabana->getNombre(); ?> "/>
                <br/><br/>
                <label for="capacidad">Capacidad: </label>
                    <?php
                    echo "<select name='capacidad'>";
                    for($i=1; $i<11; $i++){
                        if($i==$objeto_cabana->getCapacidad()){
                            echo "<option value='$i' selected>$i</option>";
                        }else{
                            echo "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
                        }
                    }
                    echo "</select>";
                    ?>
                <br/><br/>
                <label for="descripcion">Descripción: </label>
                    <?php $longitud_descripcion = strlen($objeto_cabana->getDescripcion()); ?>
                    <input type="text" size="<?php echo $longitud_descripcion; ?>" id="descripcion" name="descripcion" value="<?php echo $objeto_cabana->getDescripcion(); ?> "/>
                <br/><br/>
                <label for="precio">Precio: </label>
                    <?php $longitud_precio = strlen($objeto_cabana->getPrecio()); ?>
                    <input type="text" size="<?php echo $longitud_precio; ?>" id="precio" name="precio" onkeypress="return soloNumeros(event);" value="<?php echo $objeto_cabana->getPrecio(); ?> "/>
                <br/><br/>

                <div class="mostrar_accesorios" id="mostrar_accesorios">
                    <center>
                        <h3><b>Accesorios</b></h3><br/>
                        <?php 
                        $objeto_accesorios = BD::obtenerAccesoriosPorCabana($_REQUEST["idcabana"]);
                        $todos_accesorios = BD::todosAccesorios();
                        foreach($todos_accesorios as $objeto){
                            $existe = false;
                            foreach($objeto_accesorios as $columna){
                                //Si el accesorio global está en el accesorio de la cabaña, true.
                                if($objeto->getIdaccesorio() == $columna->getIdaccesorio()){
                                    $existe = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            if($existe){
                                echo "<div style='float:left; width:30%'><img src='imagenes/".$objeto->getDescripcion().".png' height='28px' width='34px' title='".$objeto->getDescripcion()."'/><br/><label for='accesorio".$objeto->getIdaccesorio()."'><input type='checkbox' value='".$objeto->getIdaccesorio()."' id='accesorio".$objeto->getIdaccesorio()."' name='accesorios[]' checked>".$objeto->getDescripcion()."</label></div>";
                            }else{
                                echo "<div style='float:left; width:30%'><img src='imagenes/".$objeto->getDescripcion().".png' height='28px' width='34px' title='".$objeto->getDescripcion()."'/><br/><label for='accesorio".$objeto->getIdaccesorio()."'><input type='checkbox' value='".$objeto->getIdaccesorio()."' id='accesorio".$objeto->getIdaccesorio()."' name='accesorios[]'>".$objeto->getDescripcion()."</label></div>";
                            }
                            $existe = false;        
                        }
                        ?>
                        <div style="clear:left"></div>
                        <br/><br/>
                        <form>
                            <input type="submit" value="Atrás" id="atras" name="atras" />
                        </form>
                        <!--<a href="javascript:history.back(-1);" title="Ir la página anterior">Atrás</a>-->
                        <input type="submit" value="Modificar" id="modificar" name="modificar" />
                    </center>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php 
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: La cosa es, que esa url NO esta mal. Simplemente no esperas ese dato. Lo que deberias hacer es controlarlo en tu funcion, y en caso de no ser lo que quieres, redirigir a una pagina de error por ejemplo.

Comment: Ejemplo práctico.

Comment: @omaza1990 por favor añada su código... No sé puede dar con ejemplo exacto si saber que lenguaje está utilizando es decir mysqli normal o nysqli orientado objeto o otros.

Comment: Código añadido.

Comment: @IniDesing.com si eso es lo de menos. La cosa es que el numero de la url no le coincide con el guardado en una variable por ejemplo, o no se pasan los parametros bien por url. Eso es lo que quiere comprobar, y en caso de error mostrarselo "bonito" al usuario.

Comment: @GDP Yo tengo implementado en mi sitio web, si se escribe un dato erróneo en la url muestro un error 404, mediante un `include` de PHP de una plantilla personalizada, y de la misma manera si trata de ingresar a la página sin valor alguno o parámetro `$_GET` en ella es decir **modificar.php** pero como das una respuesta si son procedimientos distintos...

Comment: @IniDesing.com yo diria que si "request" existe compruebe la variable, sino-> pagina "url erronea". Si va bien, si "request" coincide con el valor todo OK, sino-> pagina "valor erroneo".

Comment: Si es lo que dice @GDP Quiero que si el usuario ingresa un número diferente a los que existen, plantilla personalizada de Error, pero también que si el usuario borra o añade caracteres, la página no va a ser encontrada, y para que no detecte que espera una $variable que no llega, también plantilla personalizada de Error.

Comment: y porque no usas simplemente una regla en `.htaccess`? Si no existe la `URL` te manda a otra página...

Comment: @aldanux es que, en mi opinion, esta confundiendo una url mal escrita con parametros erroneos. Esta tratando igual a "index.ph" que a "index.php?id=3" o "index.php?i=3"

Comment: @GDP - lo mismo es, no?... Puedes hacer una regla si existe la url y el parámetro...

Comment: Entonces debería hacer tres comprobaciones. 1) Si la URL no existe... 2) Si el id que traigo por GET o POST no existe, por ejemplo: "caban" en lugar de "cabana" 3) Si el valor del = está o no en la base de datos.

Comment: @aldanux Nunca he visto htaccess, ¿ejemplos, por favor?

Comment: [doc 1](https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/mas-ejemplos-reglas-htaccess.html) - [doc 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32434567/htaccess-url-rewrite-if-a-parameter-is-not-exist) - [doc 3](https://gist.github.com/ScottPhillips/1721489) - [doc 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469955/htaccess-url-rewrite-if-file-not-exists)... algunas documentaciones

Comment: @omaza1990 Haber explícame bien ese punto de los datos que realmente deseas, que url van estar permitidas y cuales no? Pero con calma, y si solo son algunas url permitidas me imagino que sí debido a lo que quieres hacer...

Comment: @IniDesing.com Perdona pero me está superando ya este problema jajajaja. A ver te explico tranquilamente: El problema es el siguiente, creo que existen 3 casos de prueba:
1) Que la URL no exista. Por ejemplo borrar modi de la URL: http://localhost/daw/modificar.php?idcabana=1, quedaría http://localhost/daw/ficar.php?idcabana=1 --> ERROR
2) Que el parámetro no exista, que se espere $idcabana y el usuario escriba $idcaba --> ERROR
3) Que el valor del $idcabana no corresponda a ningún dato de la bbdd, que en lugar de "1" o "2", valores válidos, el usuario escriba "34343" --> ERROR

Comment: @omaza1990 Sigo sin comprender me has hecho un rompecabezas en todas has dicho error... Haber este parámetro `idcabana` no lo quieres en la **URL** `localhost/.../modificar.php?idcabana=1` en vez de eso quieres que se vea así: `localhost/.../ficar.php/1` o    `localhost/.../ficar.php?idcaba=1`  correcto? O no...

Answer (score 5):

El procedimiento que tengo implementado en mi sitio web.

Esta compuesto de la siguiente manera:

Primeramente obtengo la información de la **Url** `example.com/detella.php?pro=1`

Luego el valor obtenido de la variable `$url` procedo a realizar la consulta, para verificar si esa información recibida existe o no.

```
  if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $url = $_GET['id'];
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT id,product,price FROM product WHERE id=? limit 1");
  }

$stmt->bind_param("i",$url);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $product, $price);

if ($stmt->fetch()) {

  //Código
} else {
   include 'error404.php';
}
```

Si la información recibida no existe se muestra un tema personalizado, tanto si el usuario ingresa directo a la página sin valor alguno en la **url** ejemplo: `example.com/detalle.php` o si ingresa valores incorrectos `example.com/detalle.php?pro=3nfnnd` se muestra la plantilla de error, porque los datos obtenidos de la **url** no coincide en la base de datos.

**Otro ejemplo:**

```
if ($stmt->num_rows>0) {
  $stmt->bind_result($id, $product, $price);
   while ($stmt->fetch()) {
     // code...
   }
}else{
  echo "No existe producto";
  //include 'error404.php';
}
```

Comment: la idea es parecida, la cosa es que el se trae "Toda" la tabla y comprueba mediante un array. Aunque coincido que es mas eficiente y logico comprobar en bbdd.

Comment: Le falta *optimización* a tu código, ya que, la consulta se intenta hacer siempre, aún cuando `id` no exista en el `GET`. Si `id` no viene en el `GET` no tiene sentido preparar la consulta e intentar hacerla, porque no hay ningún `id` indicado y estarías intentando una consulta que no arrojará ningún resultado. La consulta debería lanzarse dentro del if que comprueba si hay un id: `if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $url = $_GET['id']; //Aquí todo lo relativo a la consulta
  }`

Comment: @A.Cedano Pero si no recibe dato, lo toma de igual manera como un valor falso, porque si tuviera en cuenta la consulta que no tiene valor, me mostraría un error al ejecutarlo y eso no lo hace me manda directo a la plantilla personalizada, pero corrígeme si estoy mal, qué parámetro o condición adicional pasarías a mi ejemplo.

Comment: ¿Y si directamente quiero evaluar si la URL es existente o no? ¿No habría una manera para realizarlo? Comprobar directamente si -->  http://localhost/daw/modificar.p <-- existe o no... (en este caso, he borrado 2 carácteres de la extensión "hp".

Comment: @omaza1990 si lo que quieres es evaluar la existencia de la URL, lo mejor sería que uses [`cURL`](http://php.net/manual/es/book.curl.php) para ello, pues tiene una serie de potentes herramientas para este tipo de cosas y mucho más. [Aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo](http://www.xpertdeveloper.com/2013/05/check-url-existence-with-php/)

Comment: @A.Cedano Por otra parte siempre se va tener valor, es decir siempre el `id` va a venir de `GET` pero el procedimiento realizado es para los usuarios maliciosos que tratan siempre de modificar los datos de la **URL** o otros... ***Pero si el procedimiento que realizo no es el adecuado, como lo realizó entonces*** siempre es bueno recibir correcciones Saludos!

Comment: @IniDesing.com me refiero a esto: `if (isset($_GET['id'])) { $url = $_GET['id']; //Aquí todo lo relativo a la consulta }` a hacer la consulta dentro de ese if. Porque existe la posibilidad de que en la URL del script no haya nada con el valor `id`. Si tú lanzas la consulta fuera del if, la misma se lanzará haya `id`  o no haya. El resultado será el mismo, porque no encontrará datos, pero a nivel de *optimización*  tu código no es correcto, porque lanzará la consulta (o intentará lanzarla) pase lo que pase, aunque sea para obtener un error en el statement o para obtener ningún dato.

Comment: @omaza1990 Pero cómo puede saber si existe una **URL** solo al azar, es necesario comprobar mediante una consulta a la base de datos, al menos de que tengas un directorio en un archivo de texto todas las **URLs** que en verdad existen y por medio de ese archivo comprobar, porque así al azar es imposible...

Comment: Quiero comprobar si http://localhost/daw/modificar.php?idcabana=1 existe, y si borro algunos caracteres, que no me de error al no encontrar la variable que le paso por GET idcabana, sino que me salga pantalla de error personalizada. Es decir, si borro "cab" http://localhost/daw/modificar.php?idana=1, me salga pantalla de error, como si borro también el número 1 o borro algo de la URL. Que me lo detecte.

Comment: @omaza1990 pero no es lo mismo que la URL no exista, por ejemplo, si le quitas hp a php va a cascar, que si mandas un parametro mal! Esa url SI existe. En si, digamos que la url es solo hasta ? y el resto son parametros que podrias enviar perfectamente por POST para que el usuario, como tu dices, no se "equivoque".

Comment: @A.Cedano Ah... Ya comprendo de la siguiente manera `if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $url = $_GET['id'];
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT id,product,price FROM product WHERE id=? limit 1");
  }` de esa manera es la forma correcta solo es eso, nada más... **Así esta bien entontonces el procedimiento**

Comment: Si @GDP me has entendido lo que quiero realizar, la URL es hasta la "?" y luego es un parámetro GET. ¿Entonces cuál sería una de las posibles soluciones?

Comment: @omaza1990 si tu URL es invariable en el sentido de que debe tener solamente un valor como `idcabana` seguido de un id cualquiera como `1`. Hay una forma muy fácil de hacer lo que quieras (yo lo tengo así funcionando en una API personalizada): creas un array con las URLs válidas, usas `$_GET['PATH_INFO']` para obtener las partes de la URL, compruebas si la primera parte está dentro del array de URLs permitidas, si está, compruebas que hay valor dentro de la segunda parte de la URL y si no ocurre ni una ni otra cosa lanzas o incluyes el mensaje de error.

Answer (score 2):

Yo uso un código parecido a este en una API, para controlar las URLs que son pasadas al servidor.

En teoría el código hace lo siguiente:

1. Evalúa la petición mediante `$_GET['PATH_INFO']`
2. Maneja las URLs válidas mediante un array `$recursos_existentes`. Si se pasa una URL que no esté en ese array se puede levantar una Excepción o mostrar la página de error 404 o lo que quieras.
3. Además, evalúa y controla el tipo de petición que se está haciendo. Aquí puedes por ejemplo controlar que sólo funcione el código cuando la petición sea del tipo `GET`, etc.

Este es un script más complejo, que maneja peticiones hechas a una API, usando el patrón MVC. En él yo no redirijo ni incluyo archivos, sino que uso siempre una Vista para responder siempre con un objeto JSON que muestra, sea los errores, sea los datos correctos.

Lo he adaptado un poco a tu problema. No lo he probado... Espero no haber cometido algún error. Si te interesa explorar esa posibilidad prueba, y comenta los resultados.

A mi particularmente me gusta el estilo de cómo funcionan las API. O sea, generar siempre un JSON y leer dicho JSON en la Vista, mostrando lo que el JSON traiga, sea error, sea datos correctos. Me parece un estilo de programación organizado, eficaz y es la forma en que estoy programando ahora en PHP en general, no solamente en una API o en peticiones del tipo REST.

Espero te sirva.

```
<?php

// Extraer segmento de la url
if (isset($_GET['PATH_INFO'])){
    $peticion = explode('/', $_GET['PATH_INFO']);
    $recurso = array_shift($peticion);
    $recursos_existentes = array('idcabana'); //Aquí completas el array con las url válidas

    // Comprobar si existe el recurso
    if (!in_array($recurso, $recursos_existentes)) {
        //El recurso no existe. Lanzar una excepción o incluir la página de error 404
    }else{

        //Obtener el método utilizado: Get, Post, Put, Delete...
        $metodo = strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);

        // Filtrar método
        switch ($metodo) {
        case 'get':
            switch ($recurso) {

            case 'idcabana':
                //Lanzar consulta para obtener idcabana. El id estará en $peticion[0]
                break;

                //otros case

            default:
                //Lanzar excepción o incluir mensaje de error
                break;

            }
            /*
                    * Si interesan los métodos POST o PUT, definir las acciones de los mismos
                    * tal y como se ha hecho con GET más arriba
                    * Aquí no los he definido porque por el momento no interesan y el método delete
                    * lo he dejado vacío para proteger los datos...
                */

            /*
                case 'post':
                case 'put':
                */

        case 'delete':
            break;

        default:
            // Método no aceptado
            //Lanzar excepción o incluir mensaje de error

        }

    }

}else{

    //No hay nada en el PATH_INFO. Lanzar excepción o incluir página con mensaje de error

}
```

Comment: Pensé que era algo más complicado al leer (API), el famoso `switch` es perfecto... no hace mucho dí una respuesta usando [este proceso](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/123605/cómo-animar-proceso-según-el-valor-recibido-de-php-a-jquery/124674#124674) pero en jQuery,.

Comment: cuántas **Urls** puede añadir aquí `$recursos_existentes = array('idcabana');` las realiza separada por comas, `('idcabana, idcabana=3')` etc...

Comment: No no. Ahí solo se añaden URLs para las peticiones . Supongamos que quiera otro tipo de petición como `idusuario`, entonces lo agrega al array. El valor numérico se obtiene por otra vía. (Leer comentario del código en el `switch` en la parte del `get`. Cómo hice un `explode`,  el valor a buscar estará en `$peticion[0]`

Comment: @A.Cedano Perdóname pero no tengo tanto nivel con PHP. ¿Un código más sencillo legible a mi intención? Mi problema es que quiero evaluar tanto si la URL es correcta como si los parámetros, después de la interrogación "?" es válido. Quisiera hacerlo por separado o todo junto, pero necesitaría saber la lógica. La parte de después de "?" la tengo realizada en mi código. Visualízala y dame una idea para amoldar mi código. Gracias. Podría tener un archivo global error404.php, por ejemplo, que me redirija a él cuando todas las URLs que fallen, me lo muestre.

Comment: @omaza1990 debido a la falta de tiempo no pude documentar el código y explicarlo con más detalle. En cuanto pueda lo modifico y te doy algunos detalles más. De hecho, olvidé algo muy importante y es que el código que te comparto en la respuesta está basado en *url amigables*, lo cual es un concepto también interesante y que se puede lograr con una sola línea en `.htaccess` (de ese modo quitaríamos los horribles `?`  de la URL y tendríamos por ejemplo `idcabana/1`. Bueno, con un poquito de tiempo te daré una respuesta detallada, como propuesta. Créeme, no es tan complicado como parece.

Answer (score 1):

A ver si ponemos algo de luz.

En esta pregunta se están mezclando 2 cosas, el concepto de URI y los parámetros o valores que pueden tener o no una URI, es decir estamos hablando de URI's compuestas por un lado tenemos  la dirección del recurso `protocolo + dominio + ruta` y por otro la consulta, los valores o parámetros que se pasan a dicho recurso después del símbolo `?`.

Existen múltiples formas de manejar o controlar tanto la ruta como los valores pasados pero ambas se suelen abordar de forma separada y diferenciada.

Pare este caso nos centraremos en el protocolo http sobre un servidor con apache y php obviando el resto.

---

### Direcciones web

Los 2 métodos más utilizados para las peticiones http en PHP son:

- Controlar el acceso a las URL directamente en la configuración del servidor. Por defecto
- Redireccionar todas las peticiones a un archivo PHP para tener mayor control, que se encargará de gestionar las rutas y los métodos utilizados para acceder.

Por ejemplo [con apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/es/custom-error.html) en archivo `.htaccess`

```
ErrorDocument 500 /ruta/error_500.php 
ErrorDocument 500 /ruta/error_500.php 
ErrorDocument 500 /ruta/error_500.php 
ErrorDocument 404 /ruta/error_404.php 
ErrorDocument 401 /ruta/error_401.php
```

### Parámetros enviados

La forma de validar los parámetros enviados es más controvertida y varían mucho las fórmulas utilizadas para cubrir este aspecto.

Lo más óptimo a mi parecer es crear una clase o función para asumir esto y no tener que escribir código redundante ya que es un recurso que utilizamos con frecuencia.

Por ejemplo podrías crear una pequeña función que te compruebe que si se han enviado os parámetros necesarios par el script.

```
function has_request(Array $parametros, $method='REQUEST') { 
    switch ($method) {
        case 'REQUEST':
            $data = $_REQUEST;
            break;
        // puedes añadir los otros case para post y get
        default:
            return false;
            break;
    }

    foreach($parametros as $key => $value) {
        if (!array_key_exists($value, $data)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return $parametros;
} 




$camposNecesarios = array ('id', 'idCabana');

if ($campos = has_request($camposNecesarios)) {
    echo 'se enviaron los campos necesarios';
    print_r($campos);
} else {
    echo 'No se enviaron los campos necesarios';
}
```

Comment: Xerif es entendible. Pero mi problema es que quiero evaluar tanto si la URL es correcta como si los parámetros, después de la interrogación "?" es válido. Quisiera hacerlo por separado o todo junto, pero necesitaría saber la lógica. La parte de después de "?" la tengo realizada en mi código. Visualízala y dame una idea para amoldar mi código. Gracias. Podría tener un archivo global error404.php, por ejemplo, que me redirija a él cuando todas las URLs que fallen, me lo muestre.

Comment: @omaza1990 ahí edite la respuesta añadiendo un ejemplo para apache y su documentación

Comment: Perdona mi "ignorancia" relativa a esto del Error pero no entiendo que tiene que ver o la relación de apache con la carpeta .htaccess. ¿No sería más fácil que realizarlo con "ifs"? O guardar en un array todos los archivos (todas las rutas de los archivos que si existan, y comprobar si están dentro de ese array... ¿?

Comment: @omaza1990 Puedes ver una pequeña información de `.htaccess` en la definición de la etiqueta de este sitio: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/.htaccess/info

Comment: Recuerda que estoy desde local, ¿o es lo mismo? Estoy desde un servidor Xampp, en localhost

Answer (score 1):

El famoso `Notice: Undefined index: idcabana in C:\xampp\htdocs\daw\modificar.php on line 57` es porque en ocasiones no existe dicha variable `$idcabana`, para evitar esto es aconsejable **resetear** las **variables** al inicio del programa.

*Un posible ejemplo:*

```
//Reset.
$idcabana = $nombre = $capacidad = NULL; 

//Si pulsamos el botón "Modificar"...
if(isset($_POST["modificar"])){
    $idcabana = $_POST["idcabana"];
    $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
    $capacidad = $_POST["capacidad"];
    //etc..
}
//En caso que no existe dicha variable no va lanzar el 'Notice'.
//Ya que al inicio lo hemos reseteo en NULL.
echo $idcabana;
```

Con esto tan simple evitaras el **`Notice: Undefined index`**.

Ya tienes buenas respuestas para investigar y aprender en cómo tratar tu *url* obtenido por `GET`, me he animado a dejar otra alternativa fácil de entender.

Si deseas comprobar que la *url* está definido y que su parámetro sea válido (`int`), podrías crear algo como:

```
//Reseteo.
$idcabana = NULL;

//Comprobamos si está definido nuestra URL (get).
if (isset($_GET['idcabana'])) {
    //Comprobamos que nuestro 'ID' sea un entero.
    if (!filter_var($_GET['idcabana'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) === false) {
        //Obtenemos el ID desde la url.
        $idcabana = $_GET['idcabana'] ?: '';
    } else { //En caso que no es un ID valido podrías re direccionar a otra página.
        header('location: pagina-error.php');
        exit();
    }
} else { //En caso que no existe el ID podrías re direccionar a otra página.
    header('location: pagina-error.php');
    exit();
}

//Comprobar que exista nuestro 'ID' con el que vamos a trabajar.
if ($idcabana) {

     //Nuestro 'ID' existe.
    //Creas tu sentencia.

   //Compruebas sentencia.
   if(sentencia === true) {
       //Mensaje.
   } else {
      //Re direccionar a otra página.
   }

}
```

[`isset`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php) — Determina si una variable está definida y no es NULL.

[`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.filter-var.php) — Filtra una variable con el filtro que se indique.
[`filtros de validación`](http://php.net/manual/es/filter.filters.validate.php) - Listado de filtros para validación.